# Python: Find condition to break out of loop

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

The purpose of my code is to web scrape a table that has multiple pages.

So far, with the use of selenium & bs4, I've managed to do just that. However, I am having trouble breaking out of my loop seeing as the last page still has the 'next' button, as a result, the program keeps scraping the last page over and over.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import datetime as dt

# website url
url = "https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=redirect&forward=main.no.sidebar.sokresultat"

# website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# click sök kungörelse 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav1-2"]').click()

# click avancerad sökning 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/form/div[2]/a').click()

# select "annan period"
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('tidsperiod'))
select.select_by_value('6')

# select "skuldsanering"
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('amnesomrade'))
select.select_by_value('5')

# select "inledande av skuldsanering"
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('kungorelserubrik'))
select.select_by_value('29')

#calculate date
today = dt.date.today()
last_monday = str(today - dt.timedelta(days=7))
last_friday = str(today - dt.timedelta(days=3))

# insert search date
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("from")
inputElement.send_keys(last_monday)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("tom")
inputElement.send_keys(last_friday)

# click on "sök"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SokKungorelse"]').click()

#get updated url
html = driver.page_source

#scrape table
with open('skuldsanering.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    while True:
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('tbody')
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for tr in table_rows:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in td]
            csv_writer = csv.writer(r)
            csv_writer.writerows([row])
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movenextTop"]').click()
            soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        except: 
            #insert condition to break out of loop
            break
```

I was thinking perhaps maybe it would be possible to include a click counter and break out of the loop when the amount of clicks (x) equals y in "Page x of y"?  If that's a good solution, how do I move forward? If not, what would be a better solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would first try to get any information out of the web page via beautifulsoup if possible. E.g. has the url a get parameter "?page=10" and is the `href=....?page=10` on the button

Comment: use for loop to limit the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results page shows Page x of y, you can check if x==y each time and when it's true break the loop.

Here's the tag I'm talking about.

```
<em class="gotopagebuttons">Sida 17 av 17</em>
```

You can split the string or try regex to get both the page numbers and then compare them.

Comment: Hi! I tried adding ```total_pages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/form/div[2]/em').text[-2:] ```and ```pages = 0``` before the loop and also ```pages+=1``` after clicking "next". As the break condition i added ```pages == total_pages```, however the loop still continues. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yeaaah, not really a fan of extracting the page number from raw text - but it seems to be the most convenient option - can't really think of another way of doing it. Try this:

```
def main():

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import datetime as dt
    import re

    url = "https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav1-2"]').click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/form/div[2]/a').click()

    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('tidsperiod'))
    select.select_by_value('6')

    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('amnesomrade'))
    select.select_by_value('5')

    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('kungorelserubrik'))
    select.select_by_value('29')

    today = dt.date.today()
    last_monday = str(today - dt.timedelta(days=7))
    last_friday = str(today - dt.timedelta(days=3))

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("from")
    inputElement.send_keys(last_monday)
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("tom")
    inputElement.send_keys(last_friday)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SokKungorelse"]').click()

    while True:
        page = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

        label = soup.find("em", {"class": "gotopagebuttons"}).get_text(strip=True)
        pattern = "Sida (\d+) av (\d+)"

        match = re.match(pattern, label)
        assert match is not None

        print(match.group())

        for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
            for td in row.find_all("td"):
                text = td.get_text(strip=True)
                print(" " * 4 + text)
        print(end="\n\n")

        if match.group(1) == match.group(2):
            # No more pages
            break

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movenextTop"]').click()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```